# Call drawRect when i click on button in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

How to Call drawRect when i click on button in objective c ?

I want to call drawrect method of a view in my UItabbarcontroller. How i can do this ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calling drawRect method directly you must call `-setNeedsDisplay` or `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method on your view - that will force the view to redraw (so drawRect method will get called automatically).